# BLE notify sometimes got wrong transfer data in iOS App

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, notify

I use the CC2541 as the peripheral and iPad mini as the Central. I transfer the data every single second through serial port(the baud rate is 19200) from CC2541 as notify. (Also I tried to transfer data in every 100 ms.It seemed to be same in accuracy)

Here's my code:

```
- (void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error{
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error receiving notification for characteristic %@: %@", characteristic, error);
    return;
}

//NSLog(@"Received data on a characteristic.");

if (characteristic == self.rxCharacteristic)
{
    NSData *data = [characteristic value];
    //NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    [self.delegate didReceiveData:string];
}
else if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:self.class.hardwareRevisionStringUUID])
{
    NSString *hwRevision = @"";
    const uint8_t *bytes = characteristic.value.bytes;
    for (int i = 0; i < characteristic.value.length; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%x", bytes[i]);
        hwRevision = [hwRevision stringByAppendingFormat:@"0x%02x, ", bytes[i]];
    }

    //[self.delegate didReadHardwareRevisionString:[hwRevision substringToIndex:hwRevision.length-2]];
}
}
```

I tried single-step debug, but it seemed that this code was right. And it's wrong in the transmission from peripheral(because the "string" was wrong when I debugged this). I got about 85% the right data. And 15% data was wrong.

the right data(string) is `"12399921"` and it will notify as `0x3132333939393231`. Often the wrong data will occurs continuously such as `0x31323339393932` and `0x3132E739393231` , `0x31323339393231` and `0x249ACACACA928AFE` ...

Maybe it has a way to correct them because it seems that it has some regular there... Or is there any way to avoid the wrong data transmission from the peripheral. Either way will be OK.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry...

I think I found what's wrong by myself.

The accuracy will be much better when **baud rate** is set to **57600** not 19200.

But it seemed the same for the Android app(it still runs well even no matter the baud rate is 19200 or 57600).